# How to add image through image_picker in shopify?

Tags: shopify, imagepicker

I am trying to add image in shopify through image-picker but it is giving error in the code, here's my code.

{   "id": "image",
"type": "image_picker"
},

Comment: What error is shown on saving the file?

Comment: it is now done now there is another error I will upload it later...